# How to Save a File so that It won't be deleted -- Like Tiny Tower

Tags: iphone, file, sdk, save

I am looking for a solution to save my game data so that even user delete the game and reinstall it will be still fine.

I try Tiny Tower: I deleted the game and reinstall it. Disable internet. Run the game, my game is still there.
It means Tiny Tower save the game data somewhere in the iphone.

Does anyone how to do it? Or where I can save the file in the iphone so that the file will be there even the user deleted the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to do it is to store it in the keychain of that user

Answer (score 0):

You datas are saved when syncing with iTunes. That's probably what happend with your test of Tiny Tower. You can store them in NSUserDefaults, or for game saves, it's better in a custom file in your documents folder. Both will be saved with the sync. But... if you delete the app from the iPhone AND from iTunes, you will loose the saves.